# How to make a progress bar like this in CSS

Tags: css

Can someone who me how to make a progress bar that looks like this in css?

[image: progress bar]

It, obviously will be static, so that I can incrementally increase it manually. There will be about a dozen of them used in  a page to demonstrate progress of something. I don't know if CSS is the best way, but thats all I can think of right now.

Comment: This isn’t really suitable for CSS (though it *could* be done using a repeating background for example). As this would presumably be JavaScript-driven anyway, why not make the script generate a suitable number of copies of a simple image (or an element formatted as a small green box)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [HTML5 progress bar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/progress).

```
<progress max="100" value="60">60%</progress>
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xhCWp/1/).

Comment: This is simple and looks very good, but not exactly what I was looking for, can it be customized more (ie, color, effects)?

Comment: @bran You may want to take a look at [Creating & Styling Progress Bar With HTML5](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, I am accepting your answer. Didn't know how simple it could be, I am glad I asked here. :)

Comment: No support in IE 9 and earlier, so you would normally need some backup for it, and why not simply make the backup the solution then? But minimally, you should provide the text backup as the content of the element: `<progress max="100" value="60">60</progress>`.